# Play transparent MOV file in iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have a MOV file with alpha channel that is 320x480. I want to play this movie over an image in my view, so that I want the image content to seem like its under the transparent MOV. How can this be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just give the player's view its alpha value as:

```
[yourPlayer view].backgroundColor = [[UIColor alloc] initWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"back.png"]];
[yourPlayer view].alpha = 0.5;//or any value you think is right
```

Check out this [sample app](http://cl.ly/22253x2T0Y2F2u0m0j2U) I've uploaded...you can see the background image through the video...hope it answers your question

Comment: I load a .mov file onto my iPad with an alpha channel and I crash on the spot. Is there another way to do this on an iPad? thanks

Comment: take a crash log and paste it here

Comment: Just making a view 50% transparent is not the same thing as playing a video with an alpha channel. Please read some more online about this topic before making suggestions like this.

Comment: @MoDJ You're right. The answer is old but it is still a convenient workaround!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot play a video with an alpha channel using built-in iOS libraries. See this question [how-to-do-animations-using-images-efficiently-in-ios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8112698/how-to-do-animations-using-images-efficiently-in-ios/8113027#answer-17129053) for a real solution via a library called AVAnimator that enables playback of videos with an alpha channel in an iOS app. You could also take a look at the free app "APNG" in the app store, it is a demo of the same basic technology that makes it possible to embed videos with an alpha channel into the app resources.

Answer (score 0):

I have been working for the video Background for the ios Swift app. Its working fine for me .The working code is below

first import MediaPlayer library

```
import MediaPlayer
```

Replace your function with this

```
override func viewDidLoad () {
  super.viewDidLoad()

  //get the main video file from local
  var path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("background", "MOV") 

  var url = NSURL.fileURLWithPath(path)

  var backgroundPlayer: MPMoviePlayerController = MPMoviePlayerController(contentURL: url)

  if backgroundPlayer != nil {
     backgroundPlayer.view.frame = self.view.bounds
     backgroundPlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyle.None
     backgroundPlayer.prepareToPlay()
     backgroundPlayer.repeatMode = .One
     backgroundPlayer.scalingMode = .AspectFill
     backgroundPlayer.view.alpha = 0.5

     self.view.addSubview(player.view)
  }
}
```

you can add view over this Video Controller View. 
//self.view.addSubview()