# To play a video with transparent background

Tags: iphone, transparency

Is there any way to play a video, including sound, with transparent background on iphone.
For Example if i get an sms notification the app should play a specific video from MainBundle which has a transparent background.

Please help me with this issue.

Comment: You are asking two questions here, do you want to play a video when you receive a SMS or do you want to play a video with alpha channel?

Comment: I want to run my app in background and when it gets notification of sms it should play a video which should be transparent. My main concern is about the transparent video.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Play transparent MOV file in iPhone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7425597/play-transparent-mov-file-in-iphone)

Comment: See also [iPhone SDK - How to play a video with transparency?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1401517/iphone-sdk-how-to-play-a-video-with-transparency)

Answer (score 4):

To play the transparent video, you need to build your own player using the `AVFoundation.framework`. Its not really hard and doable, there are some great tutorials about it on the internet. However, this really shouldn't be your main concern when you want to have your app in the background and listen for incoming SMS'es, because THAT isn't possible at all with the SDK.

Comment: Thanks. Can you please share the links of the tutorials you have mentioned